# $(...).datepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Datepicker can´t run in this page, but the script of jquery-ui is imported.
Where is the conflict? Thanks.
***Datepicker is not a function***
*This is my script*

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    var fecha = "";
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
       dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
   });
});

$( "#datepicker" ).change(function(){
    fecha = this.value;
    $.post( "tablaUsuarioPlanta.php",{fecha : fecha},function(data){
       $("#tabla").html(data);
    });
});
```

**This is the HTML**

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30"></p>
```

**And the scripts load on the page**

```
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="../css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!--JQUERY-->
<!--<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>-->

<link rel="stylesheet"          href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: why have you added http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js file twice???

Comment: Check for sure if you dont load jquery and jquery-ui libraries after your datepicker code.  JSfiddle example would be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two version of JQuery that creates the confliction . Use only one instead of two.

```
 <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="../css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--JQUERY-->
<link rel="stylesheet"          href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: @AntonioSanz Welcome