# how to fix 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function'

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker

i want create datepicker but it is not working

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

I expected calendar, but it shows me an error

Comment: Have you included the scripts correctly?

Comment: It probably means that you haven't imported the right jQuery plugin, or that you're trying to use it before it has been imported.

Comment: Please show us your HTML

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function(anonymous function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207203/uncaught-typeerror-datepicker-is-not-a-functionanonymous-function)

Comment: i.e. is jquery ui loaded after jquery?

Comment: Common issues: script includes missing/in the wrong order  or  scripts reloaded (eg jquery at the top, your script, then also at the bottom (via a framework)) - check the browser network tab closely.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>

<input type="text" id="datepicker">

<script>
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
</script>

  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
  integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>

Comment: @faiqrustamov You can edit your question to add the HTML ˆ

Comment: Code shows that you use it before the library is loaded. It is like trying to eat a pizza before you open the box. Your order is 1) load jquery 2) call the method 3) Load jquery ui. It should be 1) load jquery 2) Load jquery ui 3) call the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have both jQueryui AND jQuery included in your scripts somewhere? Question is a little vague without source code or more information to what you're doing.

This is taken straight from jQueryUI's website: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Also, make sure that jQuery is not included twice in your code as this post suggest: [jQuery UI " $("#datepicker").datepicker is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212696/jquery-ui-datepicker-datepicker-is-not-a-function)

Possible duplicate of:

- [$().datepicker is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54324351/datepicker-is-not-a-function)
- [JQuery Issue: .datepicker is not a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42129892/jquery-issue-datepicker-is-not-a-function)
- [$(...).datepicker is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37252623/datepicker-is-not-a-function)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!